# DatePicker in iphone not showing year (swift)

Tags: iphone, swift

i have one question, I want to get Year/Month/Day And Time from date picker but year is not shows in date picker,how can i get any year from date picker like user want

Example - i want 2015-02-03 or any year

Comment: you can't have all in one picker.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the year using UIDatePickerMode.Date but this will display the year/month/day. The time will not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

To get Year/Month/Day And Time, you can use `UIPickerView` with multiple components

Answer (score 0):

Do two date pickers, side by side. One with the mode set in the Attributes inspector as "date". The second one with the mode set as "time".